# SharePoint OData Query return field > 256 characters

Tags: sharepoint, odata, infopath, sharepoint-api

I have a SharePoint OData query that is returning results from a list, but the field's length is truncated at 256 characters.  Is there a way to have it return the entire value of the field?

*** EDIT ***
I think that it is a limitation from the column definition in the SharePoint list itself.  Looking into having that changed.

*** EDIT ***
The list was generated on SharePoint by publishing an InfoPath form to the SharePoint site.  Currently the fields in question cannot have their data types changed from single-line to multi-line.  So the original question has now morphed into How can I make the fields editable on SharePoint and ensure that no data is lost in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Your column is probably a single line of text instead of a multi-line of text. Switching the type should fix that.

Comment: I believe you are correct, but the column cannot currently be edited.  The list was created by publishing an InfoPath form to SharePoint.  "new" fields added to the form we are able to edit, but I am guessing the "original" published form we are not able to edit the column type in the list.  Still researching how this can be done while ensuring no data is lost.